# Shortest way to go from decimal string to decimal of binary mirror?

Tags: c, file-io, binary

I have a text file with a list of decimals. I need to print to another file a list of decimals which are the base 10 of the binary mirrors of the original numbers. Currently I'm doing it like this (where each step is one function):

decimal strings -> number array -> binary strings -> base 10 of binary mirror

Is there a much shorter number of steps I could have taken that I failed to see or does this make sense?

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean by "base 10 of the binary mirror". Based on your description it sounds like you need to read numbers from a file, perform a bitwise operation and write the result to another file, but I can't be sure. If this is the case, then you won't need the "binary strings" step. Do you have some code to post? code would help.

Comment: Sorry, this is just the terms I was given. For example, the first line of the text file is 19088743.  This is 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 in binary. Its binary mirror is 1110 0110 1010 0010 1100 0100 1000 0000, which is 3869426816. This last number is the one I need to obtain. I have it working, but I'm now thinking that I might have done too many intermediate steps to get what I want.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you reverse the nibbles then reverse each nibble isn't this the same thing as reversing the whole number?

Comment: I think OP means bitwise reverse. (the only use I know of is in the FFT butterfly-tables.) BTW: stanford bit-hacks has them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a 32-bit integer, you can revert the bits by doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinary(int x)
{
    int m = 0x80000000;
    while(m)
    {
        printf("%d", (m & x) ? 1 : 0);
        m = m >> 1;
        m = m & 0x7fffffff;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int binaryReverse(int x)
{
    int i = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int m = 0x80000000;
    while(m)
    {
        if (m & x)
        {
            t = t | (1 << i);
        }
        ++i;
        m = m >> 1;
        m = m & 0x7fffffff;
    }
    return t;
}
int main(void) {
    int x = 19088743;
    printf("%u\n",x);
    printBinary(x);
    int y = binaryReverse(x);
    printf("%u\n",y);
    printBinary(y);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
19088743
00000001001000110100010101100111
3869426816
11100110101000101100010010000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to strings of ASCII "1"s and "0"s (what I assume is meant by "binary strings") for that-- you can use bitwise operators. You can omit the "binary strings" step.

Note that "binary mirror" is an unclear term, however googling it may lead you to find the real name for what you actually want to do.

Comment: Would you show me an example? I know what the bitwise operations are, but I'm pretty bad at actually using them.

Comment: there are many-- google "C binary mirror". I did and found many examples. However "binary mirror" is not a clear term--  do you need to flip the endianness? or do you need a bitwise NOT? what is the exact text of your assignment (assuming it is homework of some kind)

Comment: There's actually no point to it, it's just an exercise, but yeah flip the endianness is what I should have said, and then give the number by still reading as the same endianness.

Comment: @Austin - reverting bit-sequence is not related to endianness. Two different things.